# How to delete extra Python install?

Tags: command-line, terminal

I'm still pretty new to the command line and I think I accidentally installed Python 3.5 twice. The path currently looks like this, how do I delete the extra install?

```
$ echo $PATH 
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin
```

Comment: What OS are you using?

Comment: I'm using Mac OS 10.11.5, I know one of the annoying things is I have to use -- user python for certain functions which is kinda annoying

Comment: Did you install python 3.5 from homebrew? It's simply `brew uninstall python3` if that's the case.

Comment: You can also check which python3 binary you're using by using `which python3`.